Bash script to copy and keep x4 backup files (daily, weekly, monthly, six-monthly) in second directory
I have an application which is making automatic daily backups at 11pm in a directory dirA. Each backup is a single .tar file, and has an apparently random naming convention that I don't have control over (e.g. 129d3139.tar , 4a98bb6b.tar , etc).
Since dirA resides on a storage medium which is very limited in space, I have a cron job five minutes later at 11.05pm which deletes all backups except the most recent one. The bash script "clear_old_backups.sh" looks like this and works fine (thanks to this answer):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find /path/to/dirA/ -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' |
sort -t $'\t' -g |
head -n -1 |
cut -d $'\t' -f 2- |
xargs -r rm

Now in addition I am looking to keep some older archived backups on another bigger storage medium, in a second directory dirB. Ideally, inside dirB I would like to have x4 files:
1 day old (just a direct duplicate of the single one stored in dirA), then additionally 1 week old, 1 month old, and 6 months old.
Can anyone help with a bash script which will copy and keep the relevant backup files?
I am not sure where to begin - do I need to somehow check much more regularly whether a file's timestamp has reached "now minus 7 days", etc? And only then act accordingly?
OS is Debian 12.

Please [edit] your question and show us what you have so far. We don't know anything about your directory structure or file names, so we can't write a script from what you've given us (also, this site isn't for getting free scripts, it's for getting help so you can write your script). Make sure to also mention your operating system when you edit so we know what you are using and what tools we can expect to have available.

I have edited the question to mention the OS. Examples of file names are clearly given in the first paragraph (they are always a string of 8 characters (letters and numbers only)). The directory structure is also given. Very simply two directories, a source and a destination dirA and dirB.

Oh, OK, I thought there could be more variations or subdirs etc. OK, so what do you have so far? Which part, specifically, do you need help with?

The main thing I wanted to communicate about the file names is just that they are not named according to some timestamp string, that's all.

Do you have a specification of an algorithm you want to program? Assuming you have a 1 week old file today. When do you want to replace it with a newer file? Tomorrow?  In a week? You might need more daily backups to be able to replace the weekly backup, and you might need more weekly backups to replace the monthly backup etc. (Finding out when the age of a file has reached a week is a fairly simple task.)

@Bodo yes, ideally I would like to always have a backup which is 1 week older, 1 month older, etc, than the current date. But the limitation is that only "dirB" has plenty of storage space to work with. "dirA" is very limited and can only store 1 or 2 daily backups at a time.

Tar is considered very old school - Tape archive. It really is for smaller backups. Now rsync, rdiff-backup, or back-in-time would be better. Are you backing up entire system or just your data, installed apps & configuration. No real reason to backup system as easily installed. Simple: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2501227&p=14207383#post14207383 Sample rdiff backup script
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2485699
rdiff Here's a simple script for backing up HOME directories: post #2 by TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447368

@teeeeee Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Unfortunately, your comment rephrases only what you already wrote. It does not really answer my questions. I think you have to save more than only 1 day old, 1 week old, and 1 month old files. A possible approach might be to copy daily backups to dirB, then delete all files that are older than a week except those created on Mondays, then delete all files older than a month except those created in the 1st 7 days of a month, then delete all files older than 6 months. Specify this in the question.

Instead of trying to look at old files and decide which ones to keep, it might be better to create new files in one directory, and then move them to different ones based on which class they belong to.

@oldfred As stated in the question, I do not choose tar. I am running an application which uses tar as its backup format. I cannot change this. I can only work with the files that it produces. So bash should be sufficient.

@Bodo yes I see what you mean. This is what I would like help understanding. Are you saying that I need to have x7 daily at any given time? And then simply replace the "weekly" backup with the last one? I am open to suggestions. I am looking to simply have some archived backups that are sensibly spaced out in time. But to avoid having months and months of daily backups. Thanks for your help.

Are you backing up system or just your data? Or how large are the tar files. My very first backups were a tar file to FAT32. I then did not understand why it never became over 4GB, as FAT32 could not support over 4GB, or I never had any backups. Twenty years ago our server backup was daily updates, last day saved as weekly, last weekly at end of month was monthly and last monthly was year end. Some logic to rotation of tapes so not overwriting same tape all the time.

Is it required to keep the file names like 129d3139.tar, 4a98bb6b.tar, etc? Or can you rename the backup files matching the date, e.g. 2024-10-02.tar? Or maybe prepend the date to allow removing it later. Does compressing the files by e.g. gzip 129d3139.tar save space? Please add this to your question.

Based on the discussion in comments, I propose the following solution:
In your daily cron job...

Copy the newest (or the only remaining) file from dirA to dirB/daily and rename it based on the date.
On one day of the week, e.g. on Sundays, copy the file to dirB/weekly.
On one day of every month, e.g. on the 1st, copy the file to dirB/monthly.
In the subdirectories daily, weekly and monthly, use the known approach to remove all but the newest N files, e.g. 8 daily, 5 weekly or 7 monthly backup files.

For renaming the file based on the date and for all date checks you can use the date command with different format specifiers, see man date.

The following script is untested, only checked by shellcheck.net.
#! /bin/bash

# similar to question, but head -1 to get 1st = newest file only
infile="$( find /path/to/dirA/ -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' |
sort -t $'\t' -g |
tail -n 1 |
cut -d $'\t' -f 2- )"

# prepend date to file name, remove directory path
outfile="$(date --iso-8601)_${infile##*/}"

cp infile /path/to/dirB/daily/"$outfile"

# Alternative: compress instead of copying
# outfile="$(date --iso-8601)_${infile##*/}.gz"
# gzip -c infile > /path/to/dirB/daily/"$outfile"

# day of week = Sunday
if [ "$(date '+%u')" = 7 ]
then
    cp /path/to/dirB/daily/"$outfile" /path/to/dirB/weekly/"$outfile"
fi

# day of month = 01
if [ "$(date '+%d')" = '01' ]
then
    cp /path/to/dirB/daily/"$outfile" /path/to/dirB/monthly/"$outfile"
fi

# TODO: Use the known approach to remove the old files and keep e.g.
# 8 daily, 5 weekly and 7 monthly backup files


The date formatting in
outfile="$(date --iso-8601)_${infile##*/}"

was chosen to show the date without time, in the assumption that the cron job will run on the same day as the backup file was created.
Example:
$ infile=/foo/bar/baz.tar
$ echo "$(date --iso-8601)_${infile##*/}"
2024-10-07_baz.tar

The OP proposed
outfile="$(date -d "$(stat -c '%w' "$infile")" --iso-8601=minutes).tar"

On the system where I tested the command, I get
$ infile=foobar.tar
$ echo "$(date -d "$(stat -c '%w' "$infile")" --iso-8601=minutes).tar"
2024-10-07T14:53+02:00.tar

The choice depends on your needs.

Thanks, this I think will pretty much do the trick. It has the nice advantage that I don't need multiple cron jobs (since you manage it with the date test inside the script itself). It should be tail -n 1, right? In order to grab only the last line (i.e. newest file). I have also used outfile="$(date -d "$(stat -c '%w' "$infile")" --iso-8601=minutes).tar" to generate the filename. This is because I think the file name should be based on when the backup file was generated by the application. Instead of whenever the cron job was set to run.

@teeeeee You are right with tail -n 1. The choice of the name generation depends on your needs that are not specified in the question.

Yep sure, it was just in case it is of use to anyone in the future.
